# Capturar la entrada y salida de un personal específicamente turno nocturno

Tags: mysql, c#

tengo un problema al registrar entradas y salidas en un sistema de asistencia, el problema consiste en que al momento de capturar la entrada, ejemplo: la fecha 17/07/23 a las 23:00:00 y al momento de registrar su salida al dia siguiente no me esta aceptando la salida, lo registra como su fuera una nueva entrada. Me podrian ayudar les puedo pasar el proyecto si gustan

Sp para registrar entrada

```
begin
Insert Into asistenciaper values 
(
_IdAsis ,
_Id_Persol,
now(),
_nomdia,
_Hoingre ,
'00:00',
_tardanza , 
_justificado,
'Entrada' ,
_tipoturno ,
_idgrupo_al,
0 
);
end
```

Sp para registrar salida

```
begin
Update asistenciaper set
Id_Pernl =_Id_personal  ,
HoSalida =_HoSalida ,
EstadoAsis ='Asistio',
totalhora_tr=_totalhora_tr
where
Id_asis =_IdAsis ;
end
```

Sp_verificar_IngresoAsis

```
begin
select count(*) from  asistenciaper
where
Id_Pernl  =_Id_personal  and
EstadoAsis  ='Entrada' and
YEAR(FechaAsis)= YEAR( now()) AND
date_format(FechaAsis,'%m%d')= date_format(curdate(),'%m%d');
end
```

Sp_Leer_asistencia_reciente

```
begin
select  *  from asistenciaper
where
Id_Pernl =_idper and
year(FechaAsis)=year(curdate()) and
dayofyear(FechaAsis) = dayofyear(now());
end
```

aqui es donde se registra la asistencia

```
private void Marcar_Asistencia(string ID_Personal)
        {
            RN_Asistencia objasis = new RN_Asistencia();
            DataTable dataAsis = new DataTable();
            //DataTable datatem = new DataTable();
            DataTable datacarga = new DataTable();
            RN_CargaHoraria objCarga = new RN_CargaHoraria();
            RN_Justificacion objus = new RN_Justificacion();

            //forms utilirario:
            Frm_Filtro fil = new Frm_Filtro();
            Frm_Sino sino = new Frm_Sino();
            Frm_Msm_Bueno ver = new Frm_Msm_Bueno();
            // string ID_Personal = "";
            string turnomarcado1 = "";
            string turnomarcado2 = "";


            string DiaActual = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd");  //obtenemos el Nombre del dia de la semana Actual: lunes
            string DiaConMayuscula = PonerPrimerLetra_enMayuscula(DiaActual);  //Lunes

            try
            {

                datacarga = objCarga.RN_Buscar_Cargahoraria_pordia_poridper(ID_Personal, DiaConMayuscula);
                if (datacarga.Rows.Count == 1)
                {
                    //Solo tiene un Turno en este día: hay que averiguar que turno es.. si es turno 1 o 2
                    turnomarcado1 = datacarga.Rows[0]["turnohor"].ToString();
                    if (turnomarcado1.Trim() == "Turno1")
                    {
                        Registrar_Ingreso_Salida_deunTurno(ID_Personal, datacarga, DiaConMayuscula, turnomarcado1);

                    }
                    else if (turnomarcado1.Trim() == "Turno2")
                    {
                        Registrar_Ingreso_Salida_deunTurno(ID_Personal, datacarga, DiaConMayuscula, turnomarcado1);
                    }

                }
                else if (datacarga.Rows.Count == 2)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < datacarga.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            turnomarcado1 = datacarga.Rows[i]["turnohor"].ToString();
                        }
                        else if (i == 1)
                        {
                            turnomarcado2 = datacarga.Rows[i]["turnohor"].ToString();
                        }

                    }


                    dataAsis = objasis.RN_leer_Asistencia_Registrada_deldia_porper(ID_Personal, DiaConMayuscula);
                    if (dataAsis.Rows.Count == 0)
                    {
                        //No tiene ningun registro de Asistencia todavia.:
                        //Por lo tanto tocaria registrar su Primera Entrada
                        Registrar_Ingreso_Salida_de2Turno(ID_Personal, datacarga, DiaConMayuscula, turnomarcado1);

                    }
                    else if (dataAsis.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Registrar_Ingreso_Salida_de2Turno(ID_Personal, datacarga, DiaConMayuscula, turnomarcado2);
                    }

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tocar_Error_asis();
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void Registrar_Ingreso_Salida_deunTurno(string ID_Per, DataTable datacar, string dia_Asis, string turno_marcar)
        {
            DataTable dataAsis = new DataTable();
            RN_Asistencia obj_As = new RN_Asistencia();
            Frm_Filtro fil = new Frm_Filtro();
            Frm_Advertencia ver = new Frm_Advertencia();
            RN_Justificacion objus = new RN_Justificacion();
            Utilitarios u = new Utilitarios();
            Frm_Sino sino = new Frm_Sino();
            string EstadoAsis = "";

            //string turnomarcado1 = "";

            //Solo tiene un Turno en este día: hay que averiguar que turno es.. si es turno 1 o 2
            // turnomarcado1 = datacar.Rows[0]["turnohor"].ToString();

            dataAsis = obj_As.RN_Buscar_Asistencia_deEntrada(ID_Per);
            if (dataAsis.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
               EstadoAsis = Convert.ToString(dataAsis.Rows[0]["EstadoAsis"]);
                if (EstadoAsis.Trim() == "Entrada")
                {
                    string nombrePersonal = Convert.ToString(datacar.Rows[0]["Nombre_Completo"]);  // Obtener el nombre del personal
                    fil.Show();
                    sino.Lbl_msm1.Text = "¿Estás seguro de pasar tu salida?" + nombrePersonal + "?";
                    sino.ShowDialog();
                    fil.Hide();
                    if (sino.Tag.ToString() == "Si")
                    {


                    lbl_IdAsis.Text = Convert.ToString(dataAsis.Rows[0]["Id_asis"]);
                    DateTime HoraIngreso = Convert.ToDateTime(dataAsis.Rows[0]["HoIngreso"]);
                    DateTime HoraSalida = DateTime.Now;
                    obj_As.RN_Registrar_Salida_Personal(lbl_IdAsis.Text, ID_Per, lbl_hora.Text, Calcular_Totalhoras_trabajadas(HoraIngreso, HoraSalida));
                    if (BD_Asistencia.salida == true)
                    {
                        //  tocar_Audio_Salida();

                        if (lbl_notify.Text.Trim() == "Si")
                        {
                            pnl_load.Visible = true;
                            pnl_load.Refresh();
                            //Enviar_Correo_Notificacion("Salida", lbl_correo_emp.Text, lbl_clave_cor.Text, "Tu hora de salida fue a las :  " + lbl_hora.Text,
                            //    "Reporte de Asistencia", lbl_destinat.Text);

                                


                            if (enviado == true)
                            {
                                tocar_Audio_Salida();
                                pnl_load.Visible = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                tocar_Audio_Salida();
                                pnl_load.Visible = false;
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tocar_Audio_Salida();
                        }

                        LimpiarFormulario();
                      }


                    }
                  
                
            }
                else
                {
                    fil.Show();
                    ver.Lbl_Msm1.Text = "El Personal ya Marcó su Asistencia";
                    ver.ShowDialog();
                    fil.Hide();
                    LimpiarFormulario();
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //No tiene aun Asistencia en este Dia y turno:
                Cargar_2do_horario(1, ID_Per, dia_Asis);

                //determinar:
                int HoLimite = Dtp_Hora_Limite.Value.Hour;
                int MiLimite = Dtp_Hora_Limite.Value.Minute;
                int MinuTole = Convert.ToInt32(lbl_tolerancia.Text);
                int Totalminuto = MinuTole + MiLimite;

                int horaCaptu = DateTime.Now.Hour;
                int minutoCaptu = DateTime.Now.Minute;


                if (objus.RN_Verificar_sitiene_Justificacion_portarnza_porid(ID_Per.Trim(), "Por Tardanza") == true)  //verificamos si tiene una justificacion de tardanza
                {
                    lbl_justifi.Text = "Tardanza Justificada";
                    lbl_totaltarde.Text = "0";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (horaCaptu == HoLimite & minutoCaptu > MiLimite)
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show("EL Personal llego demasiado Tarde su Hora de Entrada ya caducó", "Verificar Hora Limite", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                        tocar_Audio_muytarde();
                        LimpiarFormulario();
                        return;

                    }
                    else if (horaCaptu > HoLimite)
                    {
                        tocar_Audio_muytarde();
                        //MessageBox.Show("EL Personal llego demasiado Tarde su Hora de Entrada ya caducó", "Verificar Hora Limite", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                        LimpiarFormulario();
                        return;
                    }

                    lbl_justifi.Text = "Sin Justificacion";
                    calcular_Minutos_Tardanza(ID_Per);
                }



                lbl_IdAsis.Text = RN_Utilitario.RN_NroDoc(2);
                obj_As.RN_Registrar_Entrada_Personal(lbl_IdAsis.Text, ID_Per,dia_Asis, lbl_hora.Text, Convert.ToDouble(lbl_totaltarde.Text), Convert.ToInt32(lbl_TotalHotrabajda.Text), lbl_justifi.Text, turno_marcar, lbl_idgrupo.Text);

                if (BD_Asistencia.entrada == true)
                {
                    //RN_Utilitario.RN_Actualizar_Numero(2);
                    RN_Utilitario.RN_Actualiza_Tipo_Doc22(2, u.Actualizar_Sgte_Correlativo(2));
                    // tocar_Bienvenida();
                    if (lbl_notify.Text.Trim() == "Si")
                    {
                        pnl_load.Visible = true;
                        pnl_load.Refresh();
                        //Enviar_Correo_Notificacion("Ingreso", lbl_correo_emp.Text, lbl_clave_cor.Text, "Tu hora de ingreso fue a las :  " + lbl_hora.Text,
                        //    "Reporte de Asistencia", lbl_destinat.Text);

                        

                        if (enviado == true)
                        {
                            tocar_Bienvenida();
                            pnl_load.Visible = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tocar_Bienvenida();
                            pnl_load.Visible = false;
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tocar_Bienvenida();
                    }

                    LimpiarFormulario();

                    return;
                }
                //******************************************************************** Fin ***************************************
            }
```

Comment: No el proyecto, solo la parte del código y las tablas que involucran el registro de entrada/salida. Edita la pregunta y agrega esos datos, por favor.

Comment: Creo que el metodo RN_Registrar_Salida_Personal esta llamando al  registrar entrada, dado a que no hay mucha información.